# I want to know when and where onClientConnParamsChanged() appears in the log

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I developed an app that uses ble.
I was using Eclipse as a development tool.

My "app that uses ble" is installed on my smartphone.
And I connected my smartphone and pc to usb.
Then on my smartphone, I launched the "app that uses ble" that I developed.

And I found the following logs at Logcat of Eclipse.

> D/BluetoothGatt(25463): onClientConnParamsChanged() -
>   Device=98:7B:F3:52:48:11 interval=39 status=0
>
> D/BluetoothGatt(25463): onClientConnParamsChanged() -
>   Device=98:7B:F3:52:48:11 interval=16 status=0

I can think of it from the log I have found.
This log is shown by my app.
And the onClientConnParamsChanged() method of BluetoothGatt.class was executed.

But I could not find onClientConnParamsChanged() in BluetoothGatt.class.
I want to know when and where onClientConnParamsChanged() appears in the log.

Answer (score 0):

I already played with `BluetoothGatt` so I decided to digg something to try to provide an answer. I couldn't find this log in AOSP.

So I would recommend to get the process from ADB:

> adb shell ps 25463

"25463" being the PID you see in your logcat. At least you'll know *who* prints this.